# CastleWindsor LifestylePerWebRequest not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am using `CastleWindsor` to do `IOC` in an ASP.NET 5 application.

I have run into an issue where I can't seem to correctly get `LifestylePerWebRequest` working in one of my projects.

I have roughly the following code:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .Pick()
    .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

    Component.For<IAppSettings>().Instance(AppSettings.Instance).LifestyleSingleton(),

    Component.For<IUserRepository>().ImplementedBy<UserRepository>(),
    Component.For<IUserService>().ImplementedBy<UserService>(),
    //all my other services/repos

    //and then
    Component.For<IOwinContext>().ImplementedBy<IOwinContext>()
                                    .UsingFactoryMethod(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(), true)
                                    .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

    Component.For<IAuthenticationManager>().ImplementedBy<IAuthenticationManager>()
                                        //Line below only gets called once (when the first request is made), should be called for each new request...
                                        .UsingFactoryMethod(o => o.Resolve<IOwinContext>().Authentication, true) 
                                        .LifestylePerWebRequest()

);
```

As per the name I expect the behaviour of `LifestylePerWebRequest()` is to invoke the factory method each time that a new request is sent to the server. Yet, my factory methods are only invoked once (when the first request is made).

I have also verified that the CastleWindsor module has been loaded and can see `__DynamicModule_Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc_aad31f05-1937-4d39-b48f-3b2b7344d750`

Anyone ever encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

It finally dawned on me what was going on. By default objects in `CastleWindsor` are `Singletons`.

My repo/service objects referenced my Owin objects. Because they themselves were `Singletons` my references behaved like `Singletons`.

It would be nice if there was a warning somewhere that told you this.

Basically, all objects that reference a object which has `LifestylePerWebRequest()` must itself obviously implement `LifestylePerWebRequest()`.

Comment: Does anyone know a good way to debug CastleWindsor? If someone else creates an answer with a good way to debug CastleWindsor I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: You mean something like this documentation page? https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/35ebd6e5a77de289536b3862f366d6cbfad19ecc/docs/debugger-views.md#potential-lifestyle-mismatches

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: no worries. The documentation isn't always easiest to find, sadly

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic I just realised you're the author of CW, thanks so much for your work! Love the product